# SQL Int Type Default Value Question

Tags: sql, mysql, null, types

I create a field **'RankID' with Int(8)** (from PHPMyadmin Web GUI Structure page, I can found the column of **NULL** value is **No**; and the column of **Default** value is **None** )type in my table.
I found some of the Int default value was '0'. Actually, I don't want any '0' value in my table for 'RankID'. It will cause the sort action list RankID '0' at the top row of my result table.

How can I fix this issue?

Can I correct the field with **Int(8)** (NULL -> Yes; Default -> NULL)?

If I can correct my Int(8) as above. Then how can I `update` hundreds of record RankID value from '0' to 'null'?

Any comments, suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created the column as being `NOT NULL`. The database eninge is behaving as it should.

Updating the existing fields from 0 to NULL is done with following update statement.

```
UPDATE Table
SET    RankID = NULL
WHERE  RankID = 0
```

Comment: The UPDATE statement works quite well. I produced two steps to fix my issue. Step1. Modify the *RankID* field properties from `Not NULL` to `NULL`(allowed) ; Step2. Followed your `UPDATE` statement. Thanks a lot.